# What's the difference between extern fn and extern "C" fn in Rust?

Tags: rust, ffi

I've tried reading various github issues trying to track down what the difference is and just ended up confused.

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn foo() {
   ...
}
```

vs.

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn foo() {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no difference because, as [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items.html#external-blocks) says:

> By default external blocks assume that the library they are calling uses the standard C ABI on the specific platform.
>
> `extern "C"` -- This is the same as `extern fn foo();` whatever the default your C compiler supports.

An [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/697) was created to always require explicitly stating `extern "C"` but the [RFC has been refused](https://github.com/ranma42/rfcs/blob/explicit-abi/text/0000-explicit-abi.md).

There is an [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/fmt-rfcs/issues/52) in [fmt-rfcs](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/fmt-rfcs) about "should we format `extern "C" fn` as that or `extern fn`?".